# Ruby project - Sass::SyntaxError - Undefined mixin 'box-shadow'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, rubygems, shadow

I am making ruby on rails project, and after I added some gems:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'active_admin_editor' 
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

and run `bundle install` and `rails g active_admin:install`, and also installed `nodejs`, and restarted application, I got error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Home#show

Showing /home/user/railscmsproject/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

Undefined mixin 'box-shadow'.

Extracted source (around line #8):
              
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

8    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
```

I tried to change `'application'` in row 8 in `application.html.erb` to `'default'` it did not solve the problem.

Also I tried in file `active_admin.css` to change

```
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";
```

to

```
@import "active_admin/mixins.css";
@import "active_admin/base.css";
```

it did not solve the problem.

Should I add in some css file this code and where?

```
@mixin box-shadow($value) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: $value;
    -moz-box-shadow: $value;
    box-shadow: $value;
}
```

Or how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In current Active-Admin's Mixins, there is no Mixin for box-shadow anymore:
https://github.com/rails-master/active_admin/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_shadows.css.scss and ActiveAdmin also does not use mixin @box-shadow anywhere in the codebase.

It seems to be you are either using a very old version of ActiveAdmin, or you are using a dependency that requires an outdated ActiveAdmin or uses box-shadow themselfs.

As you said you are using `active_admin_editor`, which is outdated and produces the error, apparently:
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4248

If so, replace that with a maintained fork:

```
gem 'active_admin_editor', github: 'ejholmes/active_admin_editor'
```